# 404 page with requesting url in php

Tags: php, custom-error-pages

I'm handling 404 error as follows -

```
// in .htaccess
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

It works nicely.

But I would like to display the original URL he requesting. I am trying the following in my `404.php` -

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //but it shows mysite/404.php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // but it shows Undefined array key "HTTP_REFERER"
```

Any help to show the requesting URL in `404.php` page?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit htacces
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess2.shtml

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

and then use on 404.php the following code

```
$_GET['url']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite in .htaccess insteed. Your example with referer not working correct, because Apache2 makes redirect, not php.

For example in htaccess (mod rewrite should be turned on in apache config) something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/page.html /error404.html [L]
```

In this case, when you request, you will not receive a redirect, but a response from this address, but with an html error.

Comment: No - there is no navigation hence even if there was a referer, it wouldn't be the request URI. And creating explicit rewrites for URLs which might return a 404 is not a good way to handle exceptions.